# python - Variables within while loop do not reassign

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

My friend and I are in the process of creating a simple text-based game using Python 2.7.

In order to start the game, I have created a system where three save files are available (e.g. save1.txt) which contain the information for different game states (i.e. location, inventory). To load this file, I first want the user to decide to load a valid file (otherwise they will start a new game) then have the file load. After either option, the loop for the prompt should stop.

```
while loadchoice == 0:
    savefile = raw_input('Would you like to load a savefile? Y/N ')
    if savefile.lower() == 'y':
        which = raw_input("1, 2, or 3?")
        if which == '1' or which == '2' or which == '3':
            loadchoice  = 1
            load(which)
            print "You awaken"
        else:
            loadchoice = 0
    if savefile.lower() == 'n':
        loadchoice = 1
        print "You have started a new game."
        player.location = 0
```

However, when I run this and try to input a file, I get an infinite loop. It looks like I can load files and start a new game, however, I do not think the variables `loadchoice` and `player.location` (a reference to a class instance that I created) are changed accordingly.

Not only does this issue affect the infinite loop, but without `player.location` I am unable to switch areas later on in the game.
For example, this is the code for three of the beginning rooms:

```
#Every time the room level branches out, a new digit is added to player.location

while player.location != '-1':
    while player.location == '0':
        print "You awaken."
        print "Press Enter to continue"
        print "You must find them."
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        player.location = '1'
    #1s
    while player.location == '1':
        act = raw_input(">")
        options()
        roomitems = []
        #Paths
        if act.lower() == 'n' or act.lower() == 'north':
            player.location = '11'
        if act.lower() == 's' or act.lower() == 'south':
            player.location = '12'
        elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
            print "That's not a way you can go!"
    #10s
    while player.location == '11':
        act = raw_input(">")
        options()
        roomitems = []
        #Paths
        if act.lower() == 'northeast' or act.lower == 'ne':
            player.location == '111'
        if act.lower() == 'northwest' or act.lower == 'nw':
            player.location == '112'
        if act.lower() == 'south' or act.lower == 's':
            back()
        elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
            print "That's not a way you can go!"
```

No matter how I tweak this, I am not able to change rooms at all. I believe that this issue stems from the same problem that the previous snippet of code has. If this is the case, what should I fix within my while loops? If these are two different mistakes, could I have advice on both errors?

Thank you for any help you can give!

Following the advice given by @chris-sc, I created the following testcase for the code that changes the rooms:

------------------------ First Attempt to Solve the Problem ---------------------

```
place = '0'
description = ' '
possible_actions = []
possible_directions = ['n', 'north', 's', 'south', 'e', 'east', 'w', 'west', 'ne', 'northeast', 'se', 'southeast', 'nw', 'northwest', 'sw', 'southwest', 'd', 'down', 'u' 'up']
while place != '-1': #The overarching condition that continues the game
    while place == '0':
        print "The has started."
        place = '1'
    #1s
    while place == '1':
        act = raw_input(">")
        desciption = "FIRST ROOM"
        print desciption
        #Paths
        if act.lower() == 'n' or act.lower() == 'north':
            place = '11'
        if act.lower() == 's' or act.lower() == 'south':
            place = '12'
        elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
            print "That's not a way you can go!"

    #10s - down any path from the first room. These are all the possible 2nd rooms, hence two digits.
    while place == '11': #You went North
        act = raw_input(">")
        description = "YOU WENT NORTH"
        print description
        #Paths - the ways you can go from this room
        if act.lower() == 'northeast' or act.lower == 'ne':
            place == '111' #A third room
        if act.lower() == 'northwest' or act.lower == 'nw':
            place == '112' #Another possibile choice for a third room
        if act.lower() == 'south' or act.lower == 's':
            place = place[:-1] #Going back up the path by removing the last digit
        elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
            print "That's not a way you can go!"

    while place == '12': #You went South
        act = raw_input(">")
        description = "YOU WENT SOUTH"
        print description
        #Paths
        if act.lower() == 'north' or act.lower == 'n':
            place = place[:-1] #Going back up the path by removing the last digit
        elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
            print "That's not a way you can go!"
    #100s
    while place == '111':
        description = "NORTHEAST"
        print description
        act = raw_input(">")
        if act.lower() == 'southwest' or act.lower == 'sw':
            place == place[:-1]
        elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
            print "That's not a way you can go!"
    while place == '112':
        description = "NORTHWEST"
        print description
        act = raw_input(">")
        if act.lower() == 'southeast' or act.lower == 'se':
            place == place[:-1]
        elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
            print "That's not a way you can go!"
```

Successes of this attempt:

- Does not result in an infinite loop
- `place` changes from 1 to 11 and from 1 to 12
- `description` changes when `place` changes

Unresolved issues:

- I am unable to access any tertiary rooms, i.e. 111 or 112, even when I input the appropriate commands for those `if` statements
- I am unable to go back to rooms. That is, I cannot go back via `place == place[:-1]` even if I input the commands listed in that `if` statement

This is a step forward! However, I cannot tell what the overarching issue is. Sometimes variables are reassigned in while loops, but other times they are not. 
Thank you @chris-sc for you help! I'll keep debugging!

Comment: A straight forward way to debug your `while` loops is to add `print` statements and check the output (and if you enter/exit the loop as you expect). Without details on the classes (which might be too complex to show anyway) its hard to analyse your problem. Can you try to break it down to some testcase? (this will also help you with debugging)

Comment: That was a fantastic piece of advice! I wasn't sure how to change the load function into a testcase, so I wrote a simpler version of the room-changing while loop, with the results posted as part of my edited post. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your updated example you have some logic errors. Lets take place `11`:

```
while place == '11': #You went North
    act = raw_input(">")
    description = "YOU WENT NORTH"
    print description
    #Paths - the ways you can go from this room
    if act.lower() == 'northeast' or act.lower == 'ne':
        place == '111' # <<<<<===== CARE
    if act.lower() == 'northwest' or act.lower == 'nw':
        place == '112' # <<<<<===== CARE
    if act.lower() == 'south' or act.lower == 's':
        place = place[:-1] #Going back up the path by removing the last digit
    elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
        print "That's not a way you can go!"
```

Here, you sometimes mix `==` (comparison) and `=` (assignment). Have a look at the lines I marked with `# <<<<<===== CARE` in your snippet.

Similar, in room `111` and `112` you again do a comparison instead of the assignment of the new room number you want to do.

```
while place == '111':
    description = "NORTHEAST"
    print description
    act = raw_input(">")
    if act.lower() == 'southwest' or act.lower == 'sw':
        place == place[:-1] # <<<<<===== CARE
    elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
        print "That's not a way you can go!"
while place == '112':
    description = "NORTHWEST"
    print description
    act = raw_input(">")
    if act.lower() == 'southeast' or act.lower == 'se':
        place == place[:-1] # <<<<<===== CARE
    elif act.lower() not in possible_actions and act.lower() in possible_directions:
        print "That's not a way you can go!"
```

In general it is a good idea to reduce redundant code when debugging such problems.

In your case, the logic behind the different rooms (or places) is the same, so why not just test one possible route (from 1 to 11 to 111) first. If this route works as expected, you can add the branches.

With this you can limit the possible places for errors and also make it easier to see those logic mistakes the interpreter will not show you.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for pointing out those lines! I looked in the original code for the game, and I made the same errors, so that solves one issue. For the other couple of problems, I will follow your advice and keep my debugging test code simple and build slowly until I find the issue. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I got the initial save to work. Now, if the user inputs 'n' or 'N', they start a new game by entering the while loop. If their answer doesn't make sense, then it prompts again. If their answer is 'y' or 'Y', then they must give a number that is either '1', '2', or '3'. This number is recorded.

Comment: From there, I can load the number and read the save file in order to load the appropriate data and change <code>player.location</code> as needed. However, this is where the issue comes in. Although the variable has changed, I am not taken to the correct place in the nested while loops where the loop is: <code<while player.location == <i.>some room number</i></code>. I think this might be the same issue that disallows me to go back up a path. Do you have any advice? @chris-sc

Comment: I'm not sure if this is due to the minimal example or not, but check that you don't mix `player.location` and `place` in your code. Anyway, I would suggest to make a new question, since this seems to be a different issue. In the new question, try to add the relevant code (as compact as possible).

Comment: I think I'll keep debugging on my own for now; I need the practice. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @spanishinquisitor Thats a good idea :-) If one of the answers on your question solved your problem, consider to accept an answer (and therefore mark the question as solved). You can find more information on why and how this works here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit, to work as python3. I just commented out the player class usage and the load() function. Additionally I added an initialisation of the loadchoice variable. With these modifications the code runs just fine.

```
loadchoice=0
while loadchoice == 0:
    savefile = input('Would you like to load a savefile? Y/N ')
    if savefile.lower() == 'y':
        which = input("1, 2, or 3?")
        if which in'123':
            loadchoice  = 1
            #load(which)
            print("You awaken")
        else:
            loadchoice = 0
    if savefile.lower() == 'n':
        loadchoice = 1
        print("You have started a new game.")
        #player.location = 0
```

This leds us to the assumption: The loadchoice-variable must be changed either inside the load()-function or while changing the player.location property. So go ahead and look there.

This is a common way to debug code to just reduce the code with comments till it works and the check the commented code parts in step by step till it breaks again. This will point you to the where your mistake is.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see what I can do from there!